# Permutations Script Needs Optimization

Tags: performance, php, algorithm

I have functions of permutation :

```
function permutations($letters,$num)
{
   $last = str_repeat($letters[0],$num);
   $result = array();
   while($last != str_repeat($this->lastchar($letters),$num))
   {
       $result[] = $last;
       $last = $this->char_add($letters,$last,$num-1);
   }
   $result[] = $last;
   return $result;
}

function char_add($digits,$string,$char)
{
    error_reporting(0);

    if($string[$char] < $this->lastchar($digits))
    {
       $string[$char] = $digits[strpos($digits,$string[$char])+1];
       return $string;
    }
    else
    {
       $string = $this->changeall($string,$digits[0],$char);
       return $this->char_add($digits,$string,$char-1);
    }
}

function lastchar($string)
{
   return $string[strlen($string)-1];
}

function changeall($string,$char,$start = 0,$end = 0)
{
   if($end == 0) $end = strlen($string)-1;
   for($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i++){
       $string[$i] = $char;
   }
   return $string;
}
```

Example to run this :

```
print_r($this->permutations('1234',2));
```

And results will be:

```
Array(
[0] => 11
[1] => 12
[2] => 13
[3] => 14
[4] => 21
[5] => 22
[6] => 23
[7] => 24
[8] => 31
[9] => 32
[10] => 33
[11] => 34
[12] => 41
[13] => 42
[14] => 43
[15] => 44)
```

It can run well. However, when I run with greater number of permutation like : **$this->permutations('1234',5)** , the script will cause **memory exhaustion**.

What can I change to optimize the functions ?

Comment: This question can't be answered on the basis of the available information. What is the spec? It seems to be to generate Cartesian powers, but e.g. how should it handle repetition?

Comment: Most of the time, the best way to generate permutations is to use [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm).  The main problem with your code is that it stores all permutations, which requires O(n*n!) memory and is not practical.  You need to not do this, and some ways to avoid it include using a lazy generator, using a callback, or baking Heap's algorithm into your function.

Comment: `ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');` is a temporary fix.

Comment: increase the memory limit still won't be enough when doing larger permutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've approached it from a hint @hacatu said, that you are storing all the permutations in an array. I thought move this to a [generator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php), although I think trying out Heap's algorithm could be beneficial too.

I'm only adding the function that has changes, the rest of the code stayed the same. When using generators, you don't need to build up a whole array, you get an `Generator` object which implements the `Iterator` interface. The execution of your code stops at the `yield` statement and only continue if `next()` is called ie in a `foreach`

```
function permutations($letters,$num)
{
    $last = str_repeat($letters[0],$num);
    // no result array
    while($last != str_repeat($this->lastchar($letters),$num))
    {
        yield $last; // <-- one change
        $last = $this->char_add($letters,$last,$num-1);
    }

    yield $last; // <-- another change
}
```

I've put these methods in a class called `Permutation` and used it like this:

```
$perm = new Permutation();
$perms = $perm->permutations('1234', 10); // $perms is a Generator object here

// I'm looping through the results, if needed you can build up an array here, but that will need a lot of memory as you already seen
foreach ($perms as $result) {
    printf("%s\n", $result);
}

printf("Max memory: %sK\n", number_format(memory_get_peak_usage(true)/1024));
```

When I run this code (as it doesn't do much just prints) it ends up printing me:

```
lots of permutations here
....
4444444444
Max memory: 2,048K
```

When I add all the permutations to an array, the memory usage jumps

```
lots of permutations here
....
4444444444
Max memory: 75,780K
```

I hope this helps.

Ps: If you are into JavaScript and [redux](http://redux.js.org/) have a look at [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), it can also help understanding generators. If not, I hope the PHP docs will help you :)

Comment: Woah, this indeed reduces the memory usage. I tested it with 6 digit numbers with 6 combination and it reduces the memory by 33%. Thank you so much!